# PHP: Math Problem

Tags: php, math

I have a question in PHP that I can not solve.

I have a variable that has the value 5000. I need to divide that variable with a value of 300. For example:

```
$var = ceil (5000 / 300);
```

That will result in 17. I need to generate groups of 300 and discover the rest. For example:

```
$var1 = 300;
$var2 = 300;
.
.
.
$varX = 200; //rest
```

The number 5000 and 300 are dynamic, so I can not do it manually.

Does anyone know how I could do this?

Comment: 1) It's not clear what you want to do -- try to explain better. 2) Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) to get the remainder of a division operation:

```
$x = 5000;
$y = 300;
$varX = $x % $y; // $varX = 200
```

Comment: Thank you very much! :) But how to generate the loop with the '300'?

Comment: @Mike: Not quite sure why you need to use a loop to find out the remainder. Can you refine your question?

Comment: They are records that must be saved in the database. When the value is 300 it has to create a new record. So I need to generate the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the remainder, use the mod operator, `%`. E.g. 5000 % 300 = 200.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably look for the modulo operator, which is [often but not always `%`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation):

**python**:

```
>>> 1500 / 200 ; 1500 % 200
7
100
```

**ruby**:

```
irb(main):002:0> puts 1500 / 200 ; puts 1500 % 200
7
100
```

**erlang**:

```
1> 1500 div 200.
7
2> 1500 rem 200.
100
```

**[php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)**:

```
echo (5 % 3)."\n";  // prints 2
```

Answer (score 0):

are you looking todo something like this (loop 5000x then put in db when loop hits 300)

```
<?php 

for($i=0;$i<5000;$i++){
    $x = $i;
    $y = 300;
    $varX = $x % $y;
    if($varX==299){echo 'Put In db<br>';}

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you want, but it seems like you might want an array, coupled with use of the mod operator.

```
$varX = 5000;
$varY = 300;
$varQuotient = (int)($varX / $varY);
```

Fill `$varQuotient` elements of an array with `$varY`.  That will get you your groups of 300.  The last element of the array will be `$varX % $varY` (unless it is 0, in which case it is omitted since `$varY` divides `$varX`).  Is that the type of thing you were looking for?

Answer (score -1):

If you insist on using a loop, it can be done this way:

```
$x=5000;
$y=300;
while($x % $y !=0) {
  // do anything you need here...
  $x-=$y;
}
// $x finally contains the rest
```